# Grab last line of 'cat' output without head, tail, sed or awk

Tags: android, shell, awk, sed, tail

I have a directory of files on an (older) Android device and want to `cat` the file that comes last in the file listing when I call `ls`. Now on my Linux computer I'd have no problem with that, I could just do

```
ls | tail -n 1
```

But on my phone, neither `tail`, nor `head`, `sed`, or `awk` are available. So what should I do?

Comment: `files=(*); cat "${files[@]: -1}"`? But using "last in the file listing" or in this case "last in the glob order" isn't exactly a reliable thing to do.

Comment: Gives 'bad substitution' within the Android shell whilst working fine on Ubuntu (tried a couple of times to rule out mistypings).

Comment: Thought it might. Try `while IFS= read -r; do a=$REPLY; done <<EOF<newline>$(printf "%s\n" *)<newline>EOF<newline>echo "$a"`?

Comment: Excuse my incompetence, but I don't even get this to work in a Linux terminal. Should I just paste this? Pipe `ls` into it? On a side note, my phone has `grep` installed. Maybe this could be of use?

Comment: Replace each `<newline>` with a literal newline in that snippet. You can paste each line but you'll need to hit `<enter>`/etc. between them. What are the files in this directory? How are they named? Why do you want the last one?

Comment: I see, but this approach doesn't seem to work on android either. The moment I insert the newline after `EOF`, the shell says it can't create the temporary file.
The background is that I'm in the DCIM/Camera dir of my phone. I am trying to exploit a remote code execution vuln on older phones and managed to find a way to execute arbitrary shell commands. I even managed to cat an image, read the output and send it to my test server via JS. Now I wanted to automate the attack, grab the newest img (names look like IMG_20150819_164018), or at least any _single_ image and exfiltrate that.

Comment: Assuming it supports arrays at all getting the first image should be `files=(*); echo ${files[0]}` (or even just `echo $files`).

Comment: Thanks, this works (even the short variation). It looks like I'll have to do some looping from the outside, either by issuing this command multiple times or by going through the results of plain `ls`. Somewhat less elegant, but I guess there is no other way. Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for a in *; do :; done; echo "$a"
```